# Why does order of operands matter when adding powershell strings and arrays?

Tags: powershell, types, operators, implicit-conversion, weak-typing

In powershell, when I add string + array the result is a string, but when I add array + string the result is an array?  Why is that?

[image: string plus array vs array plus string]

Comment: Same reason as in the linked answer. In your second example, it's just like doing `"a" + "$(@('b','c','d'))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell converts the second operand to the type of the first operand (if it can).